# How to stop $watch when change the object vlaue on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, watch

## How to stop `$watch` while changing the object

Here is a `$watch` function

```
$scope.$watch($scope.OneTime,function(old,new)
{
// my function
});
```

---

> The above `$watch` function will be fire whenever my (`OneTime`) object value has been changed.

But I won't to watch the object on every change, I just want to fire the `$watch` function when I change the my object on **first time only**.

I also tried something and find out a function from `angular.js` script file  But I don't know what the below function doing exactly.

---

You can find this function from angular.js script file

```
function oneTimeWatchDelegate(scope, listener, objectEquality, parsedExpression) {
                var unwatch, lastValue;
                return unwatch = scope.$watch(function oneTimeWatch(scope) {
                    return parsedExpression(scope);
                }, function oneTimeListener(value, old, scope) {
                    lastValue = value;
                    if (isFunction(listener)) {
                        listener.apply(this, arguments);
                    }
                    if (isDefined(value)) {
                        scope.$$postDigest(function () {
                            if (isDefined(lastValue)) {
                                unwatch();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, objectEquality);
            }
```

---

But am seeing a pretty word `unwatch();`inside  the function . So i think I need to use `$unwatch` for the object when end of the `$watch` function. But I couldn't get anything about `$unwatch` concept anywhere in angular document. but I can see it on angular script.

I had some idea about manually stop this $watch function by this below way

```
var unwatch = $scope.$watch("OneTime", function() {
    //...
});

setTimeout(function() {
    unwatch();
}, 1000);
```

---

> **But I am thinking about if angular provide to `unwatch` function to stop the abject watching, it would be easy to handle in my whole application. *So planed to take override something in angular.js file in my application.* let me know if you have any idea about  override angular.js script file to create `$unwatch` function as same as `$watch` function. And also let me know  angular had any`$unwatch` function.**

Comment: What would be the point of a `$unwatch` function when Angular already lets you to deregister a watcher?

Comment: Calling the returned value of `$scope.$watch` as a function, (`var unwatch; unwatch = $scope.$watch('foo',function(){unwatch()})`), cancels the watch. The "$unwatch" function you are looking for is already returned by the original instantiation of the `$watch` function. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need one way binding over here

you can achieve this br

```
{{::oneTime}}
```

in your html page One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest

```
var $unwatch=$scope.$watch('onetime',function(){
unregister();
}
```

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression One-Time Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding).

Comment: See I can change the value but I won't fire the $watch function. I am planning to write some code in angular.js script file to create $unwatch function like as $watch

Comment: that you need to add in angular prototype and if you can add that function then you can simply call unregister(); to stop watching that variable.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS does already provide such function, exactly as you mentioned above. When you create a watcher, it returns you a function that may be used to stop watching it.

From the [`$rootScope.Scope` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope),

> **`$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);`**
>
> **Returns:** `function()` Returns a deregistration function for this listener.

---

The only thing you need to do to unwatch your object would be calling the returned function. You could call it inside your watch function so it will be executed at the first time your watcher is invoked.

```
var unwatch = null;

// start watching the object
var unwatch = $scope.$watch($scope.OneTime, function(old, new)
{
    // my function

    if (unwatch != null) {
        unwatch();
    }
});
```

Comment: `AngularJS does already provide such function`. that's why am asking here. Shall we add this function on the angular script? because it would be comfortable to use my whole application.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to add it if AngularJS does already provide it for you. For you to have something to unwatch, you first need to watch it, and this is why the current implementation gives you this function as the return of your watch invocation.

Comment: You could call `unwatch()` inside your watch function so it will be executed at the first time your watcher is invoked. I will add it to my answer.